# Bringing an internal hard drive to US as an emigrate

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, airport-security, electronic-items, filipino-citizens

I'm from the Philippines and will be emigrating to US soon, specifically Hawaii. I'll be selling my PC locally, but I wanted to bring my hard drives with me since they have my important files, and games that are worth TBs. It'll be more economic to simply bring these drives rather than re-downloading them all again (Steam).

After reading a lot of articles online, they say that customs has the right to inspect the contents of the hard drive and/or copy a full backup of it for further inspection. Though I'm fine with it, it's a bit uncomfortable that they can just take my private data and be on with it, for the sake of security. Encrypting my hard drive may be worse, since they'll ask me what are the contents of it, and detain me for further 'investigation', based on online news and such.

So all I'd like to ask - is it okay for me to bring 2 (two) 3.5 inch Internal HDDs with me on the flight, on my hand luggage and still retain my privacy? Is it safe to encrypt my files, or simply zip sensitive files instead?

If this will just get me in trouble, can I use a courier service and safely deliver the hard drives? I'm not sure if it's safe to do this, since I believe hard drives can be sensitive to shock.

Answer (score 3):

*Is it okay for me to bring 2 (two) 3.5 inch Internal HDDs with me on the flight, on my hand luggage and still retain my privacy*? **Yes** it is okay to bring them, however **you retain no rights** to privacy

*Is it safe to encrypt my files, or simply zip sensitive files instead*? It is okay to encrypt your files, or zip them whichever you prefer **however once again you must provide access** when it is demanded.

> It is important to remember that [even under the Obama
>   administration](https://www.forbes.com/sites/kalevleetaru/2017/01/29/we-already-screen-cell-phones-at-the-border-will-social-media-be-any-different/#2ed651775fa3),
>   the US Customs and Border Protection and US Immigration and Customs
>   Enforcement agencies had wide latitude to seize and search any digital
>   device crossing the nation’s borders. Indeed they may search **without
>   a warrant and without suspicion**. Only when it came to seizing the
>   devices **for extended periods** of time, such as days or even weeks,
>   to copy all of the files on the device, did the courts draw something
>   of a line.

You can choose to use a courier service, that does not change anything if they choose to check. Don't forget items shipped through courier services also undergo screening by US Customs & Border Patrol.

So you have no rights to privacy.

Comment: Don't forget about [plausible deniability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plausible_deniability#Use_in_cryptography).